# Can i change the default search paths?

Tags: files-and-directories

When i try to load packages on this computer, i get an error (i already know the packages work). I think the issue might be to do with the fact that mathematica can't process the network drives, some of which are default search paths.

Can the default paths in `$Path` be edited?

Comment: Yes it can. Simply use `AppendTo[$Path, "yourpath/here"]` although I don't whether all network drives are accessible.

Comment: Sorry i didn't explain properly, i wanted to remove the network drives. I fixed the problem another way though, running in admin mode forced the default paths to be local ones.

Comment: How about writing up your own answer? So that others that may have the same problem find help.

Comment: `$Path` appears to be mutable: `$Path = {"C:\\"}` -- did editing its value fail to produce the effect you desire?  Could you explain further, please?

Comment: I did try this but i wasn't able to get it to work so i had assumed i wasn't supposed to be manually editing `$Path`, however its more likely i was doing the wrong thing. The issue i was having is that 3 of the default paths were network drives and i wanted to remove those directories from `$Path`.

Answer (score 1):

In this case i solved the issue by running mathematica explicitly as an administrator, which changed the default $Path directories to all be local directories which mathematica could access.

I still don't know if the default $Path directories can be modified (removed) once mathematica has been opened.